# Grafana graph to display call response time

Tags: graph, dropwizard, metrics, graphite, grafana

I have been playing with Grafana for a while, and got stuck with the following issue.
I need to produce a chart that displays the round trip time for some REST calls my application is doing.
I am using Dropwizard metrics and starting a PausableTimer when I fire the call, and stop it when the expected response comes back. From Grafana, then, I can see the data source I need but when I build the graph, I am forced to apply some statistical calculation on my data (stddev, mean, max, min, etc.) whereas all I need is to chart the numbers from the series.

Below is a screenshot of the config part I am referring to:
[image]

The dropdown contains a number of transformations to apply to the priginal data, and I cannot find a way to tell Grafana that I wans to display the data the way it is.

I am not really sure how to do this, had anyone had this issue before -- and solved it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure you don't have to apply a calculation to your data

Comment: I have edited the original message to show what I am referring to: when I define the graph, Grafana forces me to choose one of the transformations from the dropsdown menu. All transformations will either transform the original data (e.g. counting it, or averaging it, etc.) or show slices of the original data (e.g. p50, p99 etc.) None of the choices will simply let me see my data as it is -- which is what I want to do.

Comment: @Diferdin - Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Divs no unfortunately, I had to give up and use a different tool...